# Pgfplots: Creating a bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

The figure below is a survey result from google docs. I'm trying to create a similar bar chart using LaTeX (overleaf) but so far I haven't been able to get the same results.
[image: Google Docs]

[image: Overleaf]
The output figure aboce is the result of what I have gotten so far. the problems I have are:

1. I couldn't figure out how to show the percentages next to each bar and number (only the numbers are shown).
2. "Nonalphanumeric symbols(punctuation marks, #, &, @, etc.)" had to be edited as well because when I tried to keep it the other 3 entries (Numbers, Uppercase Letters, Lowercase Letters) and their bars disappeared.
3. I'm using `\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm, 12 pt, a4paper]{acmart}` so it's double columned. How can I make the chart span over both columns? I understand {figure*} is supposed to do the trick but still the chart looks a bit weird.

This is the code I used to create the chart:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm, 12 pt, a4paper]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Text...

\begin{figure*} 
\centering
\caption{Characters Included in a Password}
\label{fig:Chara}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar, xmin=0,
symbolic y coords={Nonalphanumeric symbols "punctuation marks etc.",Numbers, Uppercase Letters, Lowercase Letters},
ytick=data,
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
]
\addplot coordinates {(64,Nonalphanumeric symbols "punctuation marks etc.") (85,Numbers) (62,Uppercase Letters) (83,Lowercase Letters)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample}


\end{document}
```

Let me know if I have missed something.

Comment: Please also provide your preamble code so we see a fully functioning MWE.

Comment: @Hoerbii3 I'm not quite sure what does "preamble code" apply. the only code that I didn't write here is  this `\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm, 12 pt, a4paper]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}` other than that it's basically text that I don't believe has any importance.

Comment: You pretty much wrote the preamble in the comment. It is mostly everything except `\begin{document} ... \end{document`. Include this code snippet and include it in your original post so helper can just copy and paste a MWE (minimal working example).

Comment: @Hoerbii3 I've edited it again now. Thank you for the tips!

Comment: @Has as @Hoerbii3 says, you need to enclose all your content in `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` which I still don't see in your code.

Comment: @Niranjan There's nothing other than text that is of no interest. I added the commands `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. That's basically the whole document.

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with this post: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. This is what the user Hoerbii3 is referring to. You will see that request (for an so-called MWE) very often on this site.

Comment: FYI: I updated your title to make it "more useful" and also modified the tags for the same reason. For example, your question is not specific to Overleaf.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thank you for the much appreciated tips and edits. I'll  make sure to get myself more familiar with the ins and outs of how to write a proper question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little complicate, but looks better. I empty the ytick label, and manually add them using `\node` outside the axis environment. I didn't do this in `acmart` class, so I didn't test behaviors in two columns. I hope it will work well. I also change the caption location below the figure. I think this is standard. If not in your case, just move it back. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm,12pt,a4paper]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Text...

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.81\textwidth, height=3.5in,
xbar, bar width=20pt,
xmin=0, xmax=100,
symbolic y coords={Nonalphanumeric, Numbers, Uppercase Letters, Lowercase Letters},
ytick=\empty,
xmajorgrids
]
\addplot [fill=blue!30,draw=blue] coordinates {(64,Nonalphanumeric)  (85,Numbers) (62,Uppercase Letters) (83,Lowercase Letters)}
node [minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,right,pin={[font=\footnotesize,pin distance=0.3cm]0:64 (52.5\%)}] at (axis cs:64,Nonalphanumeric) {}
node [minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,right,pin={[font=\footnotesize,pin distance=0.3cm]0:85 (69.7\%)}] at (axis cs:85,Numbers) {}
node [minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,right,pin={[font=\footnotesize,pin distance=0.3cm]0:62 (50.8\%)}] at (axis cs:62,Uppercase Letters) {}
node [minimum size=0pt,inner sep=0pt,right,pin={[font=\footnotesize,pin distance=0.3cm]0:83 (68\%)}] at (axis cs:83,Lowercase Letters) {}
coordinate (symb) at (axis cs:0,Nonalphanumeric)
coordinate (num) at (axis cs:0,Numbers)
coordinate (uprcase) at (axis cs:0,Uppercase Letters)
coordinate (lwrcase) at (axis cs:0,Lowercase Letters);
\end{axis}
\node [font=\small,above left] at (symb) {Nonalphanumeric symbols};
\node [font=\small,left] at (symb) {(punctuation marks,};
\node [font=\small,below left] at (symb) {\#, \&, @, etc.)};
\node [font=\small,left] at (num) {Numbers};
\node [font=\small,left] at (uprcase) {Uppercase Letters};
\node [font=\small,left] at (lwrcase) {Lowercase Letters};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Characters Included in a Password}
\label{fig:Chara}
\end{figure*}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: How do you know what coordinates to use, for example **at (0,2.7)?**

Comment: @Dr.Manuel Just base on estimating. I guess there will be a method to know the exact coordinates, maybe reference the nodes in `addplot` somehow.

Comment: @Dr.Manuel You have a good point. I have added those reference points in the code. The output is almost identical. But this definitively make the output more consistent.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks for the additional work and follow-up!

Comment: @Tom thank you for the enormous help. This worked well in the `acmart` class too.

Answer (score 0):

I need add an another answer. This is a much simpler approach. Shorten the code a lot. And don't need any extra `\node` commands. I also make the axis frames and bar color close to the google docs. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm,12pt,a4paper]{acmart}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}  
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Text...
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=0.85\textwidth, height=3.5in,
xbar, bar width=20pt,
xmin=0, xmax=100,
symbolic y coords={symb, num, uprcase, lwrcase},
ytick=data,
yticklabels={{Nonalphanumeric symbols (punctuation marks, \#, \&, @, etc.)},Numbers,Uppercase Letters,Lowercase Letters},
y tick label style={align=right,text width=3.2cm},
xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
xmajorgrids,
axis line style={lightgray},
major tick style={draw=none},
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
node near coords style={font=\footnotesize,right=1em,pin={[pin distance=1em]180:}}
]
\addplot [fill={rgb:red,23;green,105;blue,170},draw=none] coordinates {(64,symb) [64 (52.5\%)]  (85,num) [85 (69.7\%)] (62,uprcase) [62 (50.8\%)] (83,lwrcase) [83 (68\%)]};
\draw [line width=1.5pt] (current axis.south west) -- (current axis.north west);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Characters Included in a Password}
\label{fig:Chara}
\end{figure*}

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

[image]